# How do I develop a console in Game Dev Story?

Tags: game-dev-story

Ok, so I leveled my employee King Ackbar up to level 5 in all jobs and now he's an Hardware Engineer but I dont see how to make my own console.

Also how many Offices are there to upgrade to?

Comment: Maybe you should try simplifying this question down so that we know exactly what you are looking for.  It seems that you are asking for more than one thing here, maybe make them 2 separate questions.  Also, try and clearly state your question in the title.

Answer (score 12):

If you have a Hardware Engineer but cannot make a console by going to `Develop > Console`, you're not in the 3rd office. That option only becomes available once you enter the 3rd office. You will get the offer to go to the 3rd office around the 10-year mark for $25k, and it will be the final office you are offered.

Answer (score 8):

Buy 6 **career change manual** from *Salesman*

Get one employee *Coder* with level 5.

Apply **career change manual** in this employee and change your career to *Writer*.

Level up career writer to level 5.

Repeat this process for all the following careers:

- *Sound Engineer*
- *Director*
- *Designer*
- *Producer*

Apply **career change manual** again and *Hardware Engineer* be able in menu.

Now you can create a console in Develop menu.

Be ready to pay a salary of about 500k for that employee

Comment: @Joe indicates that he has a hardware engineer already, but cannot make a console.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a hardware engineer, you should have an option in the menu for *Develop*->*Console*.

Comment: While true, you also have to be in the 3rd office to have that option, as my answer indicates. :)

Answer (score -2):

Actually, you need to get more fame and win as many awards as you can to get more money. And you can also do contracts to gain a lot of money before making a console.

Comment: You need more than just fame and money to make a console. Can you expand this to be a more complete answer to the question? (And welcome to Arquade! We're a little bit different; wander by the [tour] when you have a moment.)